# jQuery UI AutoComplete with multiple cells

Tags: php, jquery-ui

I need some help with jQuery UI autocomplete function.

I have one cell which has class, and I have a working autocomplete in it right now.

```
    $("[class*='enari']").autocomplete({
            source: "getproductnow.php",
            autoFocus: true,
            minLength: 2,
            dataType: "json",
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#tuote').val(ui.item.value);
            },
            open: function(event, ui){
   $("ul.ui-autocomplete li a").each(function(){
    var htmlString = $(this).html().replace(/&lt;/g, '<');
    htmlString = htmlString.replace(/&gt;/g, '>');
    $(this).html(htmlString);
    });
 }
});
```

Where the problem comes is the situation where script adds by "document.createElement('div');" a new input field which has same name and autocomplete is not anymore working.

I need to have autocomplete working with "running numbers (1,2,3,4,5,6 and so on...)". Is it even possible and how?

Sorry for my rough language and thank you for your answers!